# How can I convert and integer into a string?

Tags: python, string, integer, concatenation

I am coding in Python, and have reached an error that I cannot seem to solve. Here's the part of the code that it affects.

> ```
> import random
> a = raw_input("Enter text")
> b = random.randrange(1,101)
> print (a+b)
> ```

When I try to run the code, I get the error "***TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects***"

I want to know how to print the result of a+b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer to the question in the title, you can convert an integer into a string with `str`. But the `print` function already applies `str` to its argument, in order to be able to print it.

Here, your problem comes from the fact that `a` is a string while `b` is an integer. The `+` operator works on two strings, or two ints, but not a combination of this two types. If you have two strings, the `+` will mean *concatenate*. If you have two ints, the `+` will mean *add*. It then depends on the result you want to get.

You can convert a string to an integer by using `int`.

Try this code:

```
import random
a = int (raw_input ("Enter int "))
b = random.randrange (1, 101)
print a + b
```

Comment: Is there a way to turn 'b' into a string?  (Rather than 'a' into integer)

Comment: ^Ignore.   I just did  b = str(random.randrange (1, 101))

Comment: If you have two strings, the `+` will mean concatenate. If you have two ints, the `+` will mean add. It then depends on the result you want to get.